# ObjectMapper converting array into set of Objects with one field

Tags: java, json, objectmapper

I have TestEntity class:

```
@Data
public class TestEntity {

    @NotEmpty(message = "strings are required")
    private Set<InnerTestEntity> strings;

}
```

Also I have InnerTestEntity:

```
@Data
public class InnerTestEntity {

    @NotEmpty(message = "name is required")
    private String name;

}
```

And I have JSON file:

```
{
  "strings" : [
    "name1",
    "name2",
    "name3"
  ]
}
```

The idea is to map each name from Strings into InnerTestEntity objects to "name" field, and have TestEntity object with this set of InnerTestEntity objects.

When I call this:

```
TestEntity test = objectMapper.readValue(*Path to JSON*, new TypeReference<>() {
        });
```

It gives me this error:

> Cannot construct instance of `...InnerTestEntity` (although at least
> one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to
> deserialize from String value ('name1')

What is the option to map it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your class `InnerTestEntity` use `@JsonValue` annotation:

```
@Data
public class InnerTestEntity {

    @NotEmpty(message = "name is required")
    @JsonValue //This is the added line
    private String name;

}
```

See Javadoc for [@JsonValue](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonValue.html)

Comment: Unfortunately it did not help. Still have the same error:
_com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `...InnerTestEntity` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('name1')_

Comment: Try to add a default constructor, that is what the error tells you. Even though it should exist by default

Comment: Adding a constructor with an arg helped, but it is strange of course... @Data has RequiredArgs inside it. I had to create manually constructor with an arg and it helped.